# javascript works in chrome, does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, action

I put together some code which works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox. Based on your selection, a URL is generated and triggered with the submit button. The "char_replace" function converts Turkish letters. Here is the javascript:

> ```
> function char_replace($inputtext) {
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('Ğ', '%D0', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ğ', '%F0', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('İ', '%DD', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ı', '%FD', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('Ö', '%D6', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ö', '%F6', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('Ü', '%DC', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ü', '%FC', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('Ç', '%C7', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ç', '%E7', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('Ş', '%DE', $inputtext);
> $inputtext = $inputtext.replace('ş', '%FE', $inputtext);
> return $inputtext;
> ```
>
> }
>
> function init() {

```
df = document.forms[0];

df.onsubmit = function () {

    if ((df[0].value == '') || (df[1].value == '') || (df[2].value == '') || (df[3].value == '') || (df[4].value == '')) {

        alert('please make 3 selections\nand also fill in the 2 boxes');
        return false;

    } else {

        var url2post = (df[0].value + df[1].value + df[2].value + df[3].value);

        url2post = char_replace(url2post);

        window.open(url2post, '_blank');

        return false;

    }

}

btn = document.getElementById('submit');
```

> }
>
> window.addEventListener ?
>
> window.addEventListener('load', init, false) :
>
> window.attachEvent('onload', init);

And here is the HTML part:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="select1" style="display:none">
  <option value="http://www.university.edu/search/" selected="selected">permanent part of URL</option>
</select>
<select name="select2" style="width:100%">
  <option value="t?SEARCH=">Title</option>
  <option value="a?SEARCH=">Author</option>
  <option value="Y?SEARCH=">Keyword</option>
  <option value="c?SEARCH=">Call No</option>
  <option value="d?SEARCH=">Subject</option>
</select>
<input style="margin-top: 3px; width: 96%; color:#333; font-size:10px; line-height:15px" 
    onFocus="javascript: if(this.value=='Catalog Search') this.value='';" 
    onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Catalog Search';" type="text" name="select3" value="Catalog Search" size="48">
<select name="select4" style="display:none">
  <option value="&sortdropdown=-&searchscope=2&submit=Submit" selected="selected">permanent part of URL</option>
</select>
<input id="submit" name="submit" value="OK" type="submit"/>
<input value="clear" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: It would help to indent your javascript code to make it more readable. Also a JSfiddle with the minimal code to reproduce the problem helps people help you and might even let you figure out the solution on your own.

Comment: Also:  What exactly is the problem?  You can't just say it doesn't work in Firefox, we need to know what exactly the aberrant behaviour is.

Comment: I have an URL, which I broke down into 4 parts and named the parts select1, select2 3 and 4. The first and the last part are always the same, but the 2nd - based on what category you select to search - and 3rd part - what term you search for - will vary. I use the javascript to put all the parts back together, replace the Turkish characters and open the link in a new window. This works in Chrome but not in Firefox. The page doesn't react when I click the submit button.